# Scale a UIView with gradient

Tags: ios, uiview, ios5, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm developing an animated column bar chart and i having some trouble.
The bars show up with an scale animation. At the beginning all columns have 1 point size and will scale till a predefined height.

The point is: I want to draw a gradient into the columns (They are subclasses of UIView) and want the scale animation to recalculate the gradient.

Until now, i have drawn the gradient, but when the column scale, the gradient does not scale with it.
As the view have 1 point height, the gradient is show as 1 color only.

Can someone give me a north to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem!

i was using scale instead of changing the view's bounds..
Was

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, scaleY.floatValue);
```

Must be

```
view.bounds = CGRectMake(view.bounds.origin.x, view.bounds.origin.y * scaleY.floatValue, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height * scaleY.floatValue);
```

Where scaleY was calculated before and is a NSNumber that contains the Y scale factor.
It's not necessary to set

```
 view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

Thank you DarkDusk for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `contentMode`:

```
myView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

This will force a redraw on every size change.

Comment: did't work. Let me explain better. I have the plot area(that is a view) and as subview of plot area i have the columns (there are views too). At the columns drawRect method i draw the gradient. Setting content mode will call drawRect on every size change?

Comment: Yes, it should call `drawRect:` on every size change. Add an `NSLog` to check that. Then double-check your gradient drawing.